# I need to perform parallel processing in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, parallel-processing

I have windows service which need to execute around 10000 schedules (need to send/execute data to all the members).

For one member it's taking 3 to 5 seconds for 10000 schedules it's taking around 10 minutes or so..

But I need to execute all these schedules  in one minutes.

Thanks In advance

Comment: You might also need to do this in 10 seconds instead of 1 minute but this doesn't mean that it would be possible without optimizing the 3 to 5 seconds processing time for each member. Also are those tasks CPU or I/O intensive?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you need to do parallel processing, you better read [this here doc](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee) to get to know the paradigm and avoid common pitfalls (its for .net 4.0 but I am suggesting you ready it no matter what because it goes over basic concepts).

If you can push down processing time down to < 2 seconds per task then I'd suggest you don't mess with parallel processing (it's likely to complicate your life in ways you cannot imagine).